# I'm trying to find a way to run Keyman Developer on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Any ideas?

Tags: unicode, keyboard, keyman, keyman-developer

As I said in the title, I have been searching for a method of running Keyman Developer IDE on Linux, specifically Ubuntu 22.04. I have looked in every corner I can for answers, but sadly, I have found none. My attempts to run it in Wine have been unsuccessful, as it either crashes or fails to load anything and everything. This is seriously frustrating me, as I simply wish to create keyboard layouts for conlang projects I make for fun. Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a text editor to write the source files for the keyboard package, and the command-line compiler.

But what is required will differ depending on whether you are using Keyman 17 alpha or Keyman 16 or earlier.

Versions of Keyman upto and including the current version 16, use the commandline tool **KMComp**, a windows exe. You should be able to use this with wine to compile packages and source files. The key is to match architectures. **KMComp** comes in 32-bit and 64-bit versions. Assuming a 64-bit platform, its best to use a 64-bit version of wine, and the 64-bit version of **KMComp**.

Version 17 (currently in alpha), replaces the window exe command line too **KMComp**, with **kmc** a Node.js based command line tool, making it much mroe portable across operating systems.